# RoR: Mailing Lists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailing-list

Are there any gems or plugins out there that make managing mailing lists (just for updates and announcements; not marketing... ie, MailChimp is overkill) easy to administer?

Or is that just something that most Rails developers just build from scratch?

Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is, because it's too easy to make from scratch, just MailingList habtm MailAddresses :)

Anyway the GUI you'll need to build from scratch.

So the question is what functionality do you want a mailing list to have...

Comment: Yeah, I figured this was the response I was going to get. Just wanted to see if there were any shortcuts. ;) Thanks.